# Extend a list in python with each interation

Tags: python

I am new to python and want to expand a list. I scrape information from airbnb site. The sites are numbered and i want to expand my list. My problem now is that i am not able to expand this list. Here is my python code. How can i write a simple function to expand the list on each iteration?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

site_url = 'https://www.airbnb.ch/s/Basel--Schweiz?page='

for i in range(1, 18):
        r = requests.get(site_url + str(i), timeout=5)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
        attributeList += soup.find_all(attrs={"data-name": True, "data-lat": True, "data-lng": True})

 for attribute in attributeListExtended:
    print attribute['data-name'], attribute['data-lat'], attribute['data-lng']
```

Comment: Where do you create your `attributeList`? What is `attributeListExtended`?

Comment: And what is your error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to define an empty list to add your results to before you start the iteration. `soup.find_all` makes a list, which you can then just add to the existing list.

The issue in your code is that you are trying to add the results of `soup.find_all` to a list that you haven't yet defined. Create this (empty) list first and you should be able to append the new results to it with no problem.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

site_url = 'https://www.airbnb.ch/s/Basel--Schweiz?page='
attributeList = []
for i in range(1, 18):
        r = requests.get(site_url + str(i), timeout=5)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
        newAttributes = soup.find_all(attrs={"data-name": True, "data-lat": True, "data-lng": True})
        attributeList += newAttributes
```

Then you can iterate through that list and print the results:

```
for attribute in attributeList:
    print attribute['data-name'], attribute['data-lat'], attribute['data-lng']
```